# How delete all content before a string delimiter (including the delimiter) without know a fixed lenght?

Tags: string, delphi, delimiter, delphi-10.3-rio

Suppose this string:

```
uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, {-} uCustom1, uCustom2, uCustom3;
```

how capture all after `{-}` without know a fixed lenght to delete to left side? problably [`RightStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.StrUtils.RightStr) could help, but this require a lenght on second parameter that i not know how obtain automatically (that is all until `{-}` in this case). Some idea?

Comment: `Delete(myString, 1, Pos('{-}', myString)-1);`

Comment: Another way is to use Copy(), and you can use MaxInt as the Length.

Comment: @kami, i not want include `{-}` on result.

Comment: @Davison Your question **title** asks how to delete before a string delimiter, but the **body** of your question asks how to capture after a string delimiter. Which one are you wanting?

Comment: @DaleM, question edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use this function:

```
function TailOf(const Input, Delimiter : String) : String;
var
  P : Integer;
begin
  P := Pos(Delimiter, Input);
  if P > 0 then
    Result := Copy(Input, P + Length(Delimiter), MaxInt)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

var
  S : String;

  S := 'ab{cd}def';
  S := TailOf(S, '{cd}');
  //  S now = 'def'
```

`Pos` and `Copy` are standard RTL functions which you can look up in the OLH.

I also have a complementary function, `HeadOf`, which returns the contents of a string up to but not including the delimiter, or the whole string if the delimiter is not found.